Using boot-repair to fix ONLY an installation of ubuntu on a usb drive
I need to install specifically ubuntu 20 on a usb drive.
After using another drive to install it on my target drive, i discovered that when trying to select it from the boot menu i just got sent back to the boot menu.
I got suggested to use boot-repair to try to fix this, but even when selecting to install GRUB on the usb i get prompted to unencrypt my hard drive, which i do not want to touch, so i imagine the program is trying to install something on my PC too.
What options do i have to use to repair the boot only on my usb drive without interfering with my main PC?

Disconnect the hard drive.

Did you create an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI boot or bios_grub for old BIOS boot if drive is gpt partitioned. You want grub installed to USB drive, default normally is to first drive whatever UEFI/BIOS define as first drive. So when installing you have to have ESP or bios_grub for grub to install to external drive. If you disconnect internal drive, it then only can install to external. When first converting from BIOS to UEFI I always partitioned new and external drives as gpt and added both ESP & bios_grub. But only one or other is required, depending on boot mode/grub install.
